# dual if statements

Tags: java

Really basic question here involving if statements.

```
If a=b and c=d
    System.out.println ("True");
```

How would I write those if statements in Java code?

Both statements have to be true for the console to output the "True" statement.

Comment: What AliBZ said or `if(a==b){if(c==d) doStuff}`

Answer (score 7):

```
if((a == b) && (c == d))
    System.out.println("True");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason I wasn't putting the 2nd &.

Comment: Going to try and re-run the program right now...I'll let you know.

Comment: There is some difference between & and && if you do a & b it does a bitwise comparison between the operands which basically means evaluating both sides of the operator to be true. However, && does a logical comparison it first evaluates the right side if true it continues to evaluate the left side. Makes sense Since, if you evaluate the right side find it to be false no need to continue Further.

Comment: It did work with only one & btw. For some reason it wasn't before. Thanks.

Comment: There are no bitwise operators for boolean values in java. A single `&` just isnt lazy.

Comment: This can be simplified as `if (a==b && c==d)`, no need for the extra `()`

Comment: @Steve Kuo you are right but using () makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

If a, b, c and d are objects you should do this

```
if ((a.equals(b) && c.equals(d)) {
  System.out.println("True");
}
```

If they are primitives such as (int, long etc. Strings are not primitives!) then use AliBZ's solution

(null checking left as an excercise for the reader)

Comment: The variables are integers.

Comment: Ok, but your question didn't say that ;)